# New class not being recognised by on click event

Tags: jquery, class, onclick

I have a piece of jQuery that changes the class on an element:

```
$(".droppable").droppable({
  scope: "items",
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    var draggableId = ui.draggable.attr("val");

    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('loc_0')) {
      $(ui.draggable).removeClass('cl1 cl2 cl3').addClass('cl4');
    }
  }
}
```

This works fine and changes the class accordingly. However I also have a button that when clicked hides anything with class `cl1`.

```
$("#buttonName").on('click', function() {
  $('.cl1, .cl2, .cl3').fadeOut(function() {
    $('.cl4').fadeIn();
  });
})
```

The problem is that even though the class has changed to `cl4` it still gets hidden, as if it still had `cl1`.

How can I tell the button to look at the current class not the old one?

Comment: A jsFiddle would help...

Comment: It would help to see a full working version of this so we can see the logic flow. However the issue is probably because changing the classname does not affect any event handlers that were placed on the element with its original class. You probably need to use a delegated event handler, or call `off()` to unbind the handlers.

Comment: Can you recreate the issue in a [mcve]?  (or fiddle)

Comment: Add an `alert` or `console.log` in the handler to see how often it's being called.   Perhaps temp comment out the fadeout/fadein code to see if there's another handler that you haven't found.